# python HTTPServer return multipart/form-data (returning multiple binary files)

Tags: python, python-3.x, http-headers, multipart

due to the env I am working I steer to use only the standard libs.

My goal is return in a single do_GET multiple binary files.

Below is an stub that I just can't figure out why is it not working. I did browse SO extensively and other places, including the RFCs.

I am testing this via curl and firefox to no avail.

Any hints appreciated.

```
def do_GET(self):



        parsed_path = parse.urlparse(self.path)

        #ret="mensaje de vuelta"
        #print("*** {} ***".format(ret))
        #message = ret+'\r\n'

        self.send_response(200)  

        self.send_header('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary=qazwsxedcrfv')

        #
        #                 
        self.end_headers()
        #
        #
        self.wfile.write(b"\r\n--qazwsxedcrfv\r\n")

        self.wfile.write(b'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="datafile1"; filename="'+
                         bytes(os.path.basename(files[0]).encode("utf8"))+b'"\r\n')
        self.wfile.write(b'Content-Type: image/jpg\r\n')
        self.wfile.write(b"\r\n")

        pic=open(files[0],"rb").read()   
        self.wfile.write(pic)

        self.wfile.write(b"\r\n--qazwsxedcrfv\r\n")
        self.wfile.write(b'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="datafile1"; filename="'+
                         bytes(os.path.basename(files[1]).encode("utf8"))+b'"\r\n')
        self.wfile.write(b'Content-Type: image/jpg\r\n')
        self.wfile.write(b"\r\n")

        pic=open(files[1],"rb").read()   
        self.wfile.write(pic)

        self.wfile.write(b"\r\n--qazwsxedcrfv--\r\n")
        #
```